# what the difference between core service, core foundation and core data?

Tags: macos

When coding MacOS, there are several options I can use. Core Services, Core Foundation, and Core Data. What's the difference between them? Are they pure C++ code?

Comment: The only thing they all have in common is the prefix "Core". Each of these have good documentation on the Apple Dev site.

Comment: Surely just googling any of those things will give you a good idea of what they are and how they are different.

Answer (score 4):

They all perform different things and are implemented in either C or Objective-C:

[Core Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreServicesReferenceCollection/_index.html):

> This collection of documents provides the API reference for the Core
>   Services framework, which encompasses many fundamental operating
>   system services used by Carbon applications.

[Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CoreFoundation_Collection/_index.html):

> Core Foundation is a framework that provides fundamental software
>   services useful to application services, application environments, and
>   to applications themselves. Core Foundation also provides abstractions
>   for common data types, facilitates internationalization with Unicode
>   string storage, and offers a suite of utilities such as plug-in
>   support, XML property lists, URL resource access, and preferences.

[Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/_index.html):

> This collection of documents provides the API reference for the Core
>   Data framework. Core Data provides object graph management and
>   persistence for Foundation and Cocoa applications. For more details,
>   see “Core Data Basics”.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [Apple's diagram](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH270-BCICAIFJ):

[image: MacOS Frameworks layers]

You can see right away that Core Services is a layer in the MacOS software ecosystem that includes Core Foundation plus much more. Core Foundation is C-based, so you can of course call it easily from C++, but not all the frameworks in the Core Services layer have C-only API's.

Core Data is another framework in the Core Services layer, and is a good example of a Core Services API with an Objective-C API. Core Data and Core Foundation do completely different things -- neither is a suitable substitute for the other.

Answer (score 0):

These are libraries which you can link against and use in your code. The *code* apple uses in them is intentionally obscure from us, and usually you would use Objective-C to consume them (one presumes they are written in Objective-C, but there are some C++ libs). You can link against these and many other Apple libraries. See [Apples Core Services Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=Core%20Services%20Layer) for a description of the frameworks. There are many, and they are diverse and too large in scope to describe here.

Answer (score 0):

They are all quite different, actually-and they are written in Objective-C, not C++.  You can't access the code inside them anyway, only the interfaces they expose to you, so that's actually irrelevant.

The Apple developer docs are an excellent resource:

[Core Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/CoreServicesReferenceCollection/_index.html)

[Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

[Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html)